# Building a classification rule for geographical mapping of cell phone number

Tags: classification

I have a database of some 10000 cell-numbers with mapping of geographical areas they are associated to. I believe the first 5-6 characters in the numbers can point to the geo. area the cell number belongs to.

I want to build the rules for such mapping so that geographical area for a new number can be calculated. Can someone point how should I approach the problem?

**Update**: I am not sure how many digits are specific to geo. location. It is only my guess that 5-6 digits may be involved.

Also, more than one set of digits can be associated to a particular geo-area. Every operator will have their own digit-set to refer to area and my database has cell-numbers from several operators.

Comment: Maybe http://gis.stackexchange.com/ would be more appropriate in your case. Anyway, you might think of updating the title of your question because as it stands it doesn't really reflect your aims (the use of "classifier" is misleading here).

Comment: I'm not understanding something: if a prefix of the numbers "points to" a geographic region, isn't that your solution?  If a new number has a unique new prefix and you are hoping to determine (or guess) which region it might indicate, then you need to supply more information about the nature of the prefix-region relation in order to begin addressing this problem.

Comment: @chl Well, I think it is a general stats question. Instead of GIS, it could have been mapping to anything else. Can you suggest me a better title? I am sorry I am very new to http://stats.stackexchange.com and not very good with stats.

Comment: "Building a classification rule for geographical mapping of cell number"? Maybe provide additional details, per @whuber's request, and this might be clarified further.

Comment: @chl: Done. Thanx for the title suggestion. And, I have provided more information.

Answer (score 3):

Ah!  "Cell" apparently means "cell *phone*" (rather than a generic cell such as a square on a map grid).  Thus, for each prefix, you would like to identify a geographic region in which that prefix is found.  These regions are not predefined; rather, you would like to estimate their extents from the data you have.  (This is why it's not a simple database tabulation problem.)

If this is right, then you probably would like to apply a "[concave hull](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=concave+hull)" algorithm with a GIS.  Each prefix gives a set of points in your database which translates to a polygonal region (the concave hull).  By applying this algorithm separately for each prefix, you would obtain a set of possibly overlapping geographic regions.

[Statistical clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis) algorithms look promising in this context, but they don't seem appropriate for several reasons.  First, you already have the clusters: the cell phone number prefix gives the cluster identifiers.  Second, the clusters might not be spatially separated, because sets of distinct ids can be geographically overlaid.

If you want to pursue the concave hull idea, we can migrate this question to the GIS site.

Comment: Thanx. I would like to try concave hull algorithm.

Comment: @curious PostGIS, Python, and R solutions are referenced at http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/1200/664 .  (Ignore references to "convex hull" algorithms and focus on "concave hull" and "alpha shapes".)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using relational database. R has a nice implementation of this (see this post on [sqldf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169551/sql-like-functionality-in-r)). MS Access (or even Excel) will work just as well.

The idea here is you want to create a table that maps a number (as you say, of 5/6 digits) to a geographical region (75 or however many you have). Then, you join your table of 10000 records onto your reference table.

Let table `mydata` contain your 10000 records and holds at least 1 column:

1. ID - contains your 'cell number'

Let table `myreftable` contain your reference table, which should have exactly 1 row for each geographic region, and holds 2 columns:

1. ID - contains the relevent 5/6 digits of your 'cell number'
2. Geo - contains the description of the geographic region

The table you'd want would be generate by the following SQL:

```
select
   m.ID as cell_number
   ,r.Geo as geo_region
from mydata m
inner join myreftable r on left(m.ID,6)=r.ID
```

... where 'left()' is any function that takes the first 'n' characters of a string. Each database has different text/string functions you can use for this purpose.